Didn't find class on path: DexPathList at runtime
All code can be found here
I'm trying to create a Kotlin application with Compose and Dagger, and when I run the app it simply logs a runtime error " java.lang.RuntimeException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList".
I tried all methods proposed on github to solve same error, none of those helped.
The build is successfull, but at runtime I receive an error. I've gone through the content of my APK file and located the class that is supposedly does not exists:
APK content
Complete error log:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tstrade, PID: 5771
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.tstrade.MyApplication package com.example.tstrade: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tstrade.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.tstrade/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~0aEP9N-to8KWK8_bUN3_qw==/com.example.tstrade-ICE0Zr5srgLSyF6wlZQibw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~0aEP9N-to8KWK8_bUN3_qw==/com.example.tstrade-ICE0Zr5srgLSyF6wlZQibw==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tstrade.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.tstrade/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~0aEP9N-to8KWK8_bUN3_qw==/com.example.tstrade-ICE0Zr5srgLSyF6wlZQibw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~0aEP9N-to8KWK8_bUN3_qw==/com.example.tstrade-ICE0Zr5srgLSyF6wlZQibw==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:51)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1282)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
Lcom/example/tstrade/Hilt_MyApplication;
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
.. 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
com.example.tstrade.Hilt_MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.tstrade/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~0aEP9N-to8KWK8_bUN3_qw==/com.example.tstrade-ICE0Zr5srgLSyF6wlZQibw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~0aEP9N-to8KWK8_bUN3_qw==/com.example.tstrade-ICE0Zr5srgLSyF6wlZQibw==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 19 more 
Suppressed: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/tstrade/Hilt_MyApplication;]


I couldn't reproduce the error

Thanks for the attention, just was able to fix it. Cannot say how I resolved it though. I added a bunch of dependencies from this post.
After I added these dependencies, issue was resolved. I decided to remove them one by one to determine which dependency exactly helped. I removed them all and the issue was still absent. So basically everything started to work fine without any new dependencies.
I guess that there was a conflict in my dependencies of some kind, and adding new ones, rebuilding it and then clearing them somehow resolved the issue. Though standard rebuild didn't help.
